# Watermark not showing when, print the html file to pdf

Tags: html, css, pdf

I have a HTML webpage. In center, the page have a watermark image(any format jpg, png, svg) placed using CSS. If i print the html page. It showing all webpage contents, except the watermark. What i'll do for showing that watermark.

**CSS**

```
.inner-print-content {
    margin-left: 15mm;
    margin-right: 15mm;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-image: url(/logo.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Way do you not just use a normal IMG tag for the watermark? Here is a basic example, if you print this page the happy emoji will be printed but the sad one won't, because the sad one is a css background image and the happy one is just an normal img tag.

```css
div  {
    background-image: url("https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/google/119/crying-face_1f622.png");
    background-size: cover;
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/google/119/grinning-face_1f600.png"  width=100" height="100"></img>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply . It also working. But,the real solution is user need to enable 2 options in chrome  print settings in left down panel